# C# - Extracting satellite two line elements from a text file

Tags: c#, combobox, text-files, satellite, satellite-navigation

I'm very new to c# and programming in general so I apologise if this doesn't make sense... 
I need to be able to search a textbox or combobox to read a notepad file containing many satellite two line element codes.
The text file is set out like this:

```
0 VANGUARD 1
1 00005U 58002B   14242.42781498  .00000028  00000-0  24556-4 0  2568
2 00005 034.2497 271.4959 1848458 183.2227 175.4750 10.84383299975339
0 TRANSIT 2A
1 00045U 60007A   14245.43855606  .00000265  00000-0  95096-4 0  2208
2 00045 066.6958 193.0879 0251338 053.7315 060.2264 14.33038972819563
0 EXPLORER 11
1 00107U 61013A   14245.36883128  .00001088  00000-0  12832-3 0  1217
2 00107 028.7916 229.2883 0562255 219.9933 302.0575 14.05099145667434
```

Etc.

I need to search the box for the only satellite's name (the name after the 0 in the 'first' row) and extract that name into another textbox, and to use in my code. Additionally, I need to seperately extract the 2 lines of code directly beneath the name selected in the box (also to use in the code).

I have written code to use these two line elements, but I'm not able to automatically put them in my code.

Thank you

Comment: why can'y you just use the split method.. then from there you can check to see if the split lines data.lenth is less than the length of the longest lines which seem to be every 3rd line it starts with ) then name..this is very easy in nature actually .. you can read all the text at once and split that info I just did the same thing for file that we get from Oil readings do yo also want someone to code this for you..?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what the split method is... I'd like to try code it myself but I'm lost on where to start. I also forgot to say that I need to ignore the 0 when searching the names

Comment: You need to lean if you want to write programs. Here are the methods and other items you need to use (and read up on): `Using System.IO; File.ReadAllLines(); Split(); Arrays.. And, if you are feeling strong Regular Expressions ie RegEx`

Comment: I have left you an almost fully coded example you can use that as a basis and use the debugger and step through the code to see if any other conditions need to be checked..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for this task.

(I assume that the letters/numbers block after the name is also part of the name)

**This code will do the following:**

- capture the name of the satellite and the two lines into a `Satellite` object
- populate a ComboBox with the names of the satellite
- whenever you selected a satellite you can know which one it was
- a search box that searches for the first satellite beginning with the typed text

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private readonly BindingList<Satellite> _satellites = new BindingList<Satellite>();
        private string _input = @"
0 VANGUARD 1
1 00005U 58002B   14242.42781498  .00000028  00000-0  24556-4 0  2568
2 00005 034.2497 271.4959 1848458 183.2227 175.4750 10.84383299975339
0 TRANSIT 2A
1 00045U 60007A   14245.43855606  .00000265  00000-0  95096-4 0  2208
2 00045 066.6958 193.0879 0251338 053.7315 060.2264 14.33038972819563
0 EXPLORER 11
1 00107U 61013A   14245.36883128  .00001088  00000-0  12832-3 0  1217
2 00107 028.7916 229.2883 0562255 219.9933 302.0575 14.05099145667434
";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var regexObj =
                new Regex(@"(?<=^\d+\s(?<name>[\w|\d|\s]+))\r\n(?<line1>(?<=^).*)\r\n(?<line2>(?<=^).*(?=\r))",
                    RegexOptions.Multiline);
            Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(_input);

            while (matchResult.Success)
            {
                string name = matchResult.Groups["name"].Value;
                string line1 = matchResult.Groups["line1"].Value;
                string line2 = matchResult.Groups["line2"].Value;


                var regexObj1 = new Regex(@"(?<=^[1|2].*)([\d\w.-]+)");
                Match matchResult1 = regexObj1.Match(line1);
                var numbers1 = new List<string>();
                while (matchResult1.Success)
                {
                    string s = matchResult1.Value;
                    numbers1.Add(s);
                    matchResult1 = matchResult1.NextMatch();
                }

                var regexObj2 = new Regex(@"(?<=^[1|2].*)([\d\w.-]+)");
                Match matchResult2 = regexObj2.Match(line2);
                var numbers2 = new List<string>();
                while (matchResult2.Success)
                {
                    string s = matchResult2.Value;
                    numbers2.Add(s);
                    matchResult2 = matchResult2.NextMatch();
                }

                _satellites.Add(new Satellite
                {
                    Name = name,
                    Line1 = line1,
                    Line2 = line2,
                    Numbers1 = numbers1,
                    Numbers2 = numbers2
                });


                matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
            }

            comboBox1.DataSource = _satellites;
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var comboBox = (ComboBox) sender;
            var satellites = comboBox.DataSource as List<Satellite>;
            if (satellites != null && comboBox.SelectedIndex > -1)
            {
                Satellite selectedSatellite = satellites[comboBox.SelectedIndex];
                Console.WriteLine("Selected satellite: " + selectedSatellite.Name);
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox) sender;
            string text = textBox.Text;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            {
                Satellite satellite =
                    _satellites.FirstOrDefault((s => s.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(text.ToLower())));
                if (satellite != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found satellite: " + satellite);
                }
            }
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox) sender;
            string text = textBox.Text;
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            {
                Satellite satellite =
                    _satellites.FirstOrDefault(
                        s => s.Numbers1.Any(t => t.StartsWith(text)) || s.Numbers2.Any(t => t.StartsWith(text)));
                if (satellite != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found satellite: " + satellite);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Satellite
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Line1 { get; set; }
        public string Line2 { get; set; }
        public List<string> Numbers1 { get; set; }
        public List<string> Numbers2 { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Name: {0}", Name);
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant thank you. But how would I incorporate this with a combobox? I can link the combobox to a text file but I will only need the 3 separate lines of the satellite as output

Comment: I have updated the code to capture the name and the two lines, regarding your comment can you explain a little more what you need ?

Comment: I hope this makes sense... But it's for a satellite locating program. I use the two line element codes below the satellite to find the coordinates of the satellite and where it is in relationship to a base location (my GPS coordinates). I have windows form application outputting an individual satellite's coordinates, azimuth and elevation angles etc. I would like to have a textbox that is able to search a database of satellite names and elements. Once a satellite name is chosen, the 2 lines of numbers beneath that name will be shown in a separate textbox, which I can then put in my code.

Comment: See my new code ! I'll let you do the rest, should probably be straightforward :D

Comment: Hi I've got the 3 example satellites linked up to the combobox and it's outputting the correct elements when a specific satellite is chosen from the name list. But I'm not able to add more satellites to this list (eg 0 ISS (ZARYA), 1 25544U 98067A   14245.51991314  .00013026  00000-0  23431-3 0   101, 2 25544 051.6451 076.2836 0003709 072.7397 020.6341 15.50183561903328), nor am I able to get the code to search a text file for these elements.

Comment: I've updated the code, now you can add a satellite and it will show up, the 2nd textbox allows you to search for one of these numbers; also I've separated all these numbers as distinct elements as you'll see.

Comment: I've just realised that I wasn't able to add and search for ISS (ZARYA) because it doesn't contain a number after the satellite. I don't need the second textbox to search the satellite numbers as a drop down combobox is good enough for the selection. Is there a way to search satellite lists with some names containing no numbers. The textfile I'd like to able to search has a few thousand satellites and will need to be updated when new satellite elements are released. Can that list be replaced with a textfile link?

Comment: Advice : ask another question because it's becoming too broad, it is likely to get closed otherwise. I think I've answered the main point of your question (extracting satellites from text) so if you're satisfied with my answer, accept it and you can always notify me about your new question and I'll try to answer it. See the help regarding what can/should be asked : http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic :D

Comment: I'm sorry I just got caught up as this is quite new to me. Simply, how would I search a satellite in that list that doesn't contain a number after it's name? Eg. I'm able to search and select satellite TRANSIT 2A, but a satellite with the name ISS (ZARYA) does not appear in the combobox even though I've added it to the list of satellites. Thank you

Comment: 1\ You should paste the entire code, adding a satellite later works for me. 2\ I've used `StartsWith(...)` as a predicate for searching by name, feel free to use anything else such as `Contains`.

Comment: I've figured out my problem. The code wasn't recognising satellite names that contained brackets. I changed the new Regex line name section to this <name>[\w|\d|\s|\()] and now it's picking up names such as ISS (ZAYRA). I hope this is correct and doesn't change the rest of the code. Thank you for your help

Comment: There's meant to be a \ before the brackets but the copy and paste didn't pick it up.

Comment: Great, don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it ! :D

Answer (score 1):

here is something that you can try quick and dirty that I have come up with.

> 1st place the file in a folder on your local hard drive.
>
> 2nd where I have filepath defined replace it with your actual file path and know how to use the @ symbol and what it means in C#
>
> 3rd notice how I used the string .Replace Method.. you will have to tweak it I just gave you an Idea I am not going to write the entire code for you.. good luck.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fileName = string.Empty;
    var filePath = @"C:\Users\myfolder\Documents\RGReports\"; //for testing purposes only 
    List<string> listNames = new List<string>();
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@filePath);
    foreach (string file in filePaths)
    {
        if (file.Contains(".txt"))
        {
            fileName = file;
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
            {
                //string s = String.Empty;
                var tempFile = sr.ReadToEnd();
                var splitFile = tempFile.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                foreach (string str in splitFile)
                {
                    if (str.Length == 12)
                    {
                        listNames.Add(str.Substring(0, str.Length).Replace("0", "").Replace("1", "").Replace("2A",""));
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(str);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Results will yield the following for names for example tested in a Console App
>
> VANGUARD
>
> TRANSIT
>
> EXPLORER

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex you could do something like this:

```
public List<string> GetSatelliteNames(string input)
{
    string[] split = input.split(new string[2] { "\n", "\r\n" });
    List<string> result = new List<string>();    
    foreach (var s in split)
    {
        string splitagain = s.split(new char[1] { ' ' });
        if (s[0] == "0") result.add(s[1]);
    }
    return result;
}
```